# showing negative excel axis without label

Tags: microsoft-excel, axis

I have a graph with one negative value. I'd like to be able to

1. Start the graph from the lowest value (in my example, -1) instead of 0
2. I'd like the major axis to still show every 10 units from 0, so since I'm starting at -1, I'd like to show at 0, 10, 20 etc...

A screen shot of what want to AVOID

[image]

Comment: There are lots of tutorials for this, first result I got on Google is  http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s311/excel-charts.htm

Comment: Not that I found, I think you are miss-understanding my problem. I need the labels to start at 0 but negative values to be displayed.

Comment: How do you think this is possible? I mean, how do you show something at -N if you don't show less than 0? Are you wanting it to be displayed in the graph, or for it show at the -N position but just not having a negative Y axis?

Comment: I have attempted to make the question more clear. I just want that axis to start at -1 but the labels to start at 0 and increase in 10s.

Comment: I have edited your post , is my edit correct?

Comment: no that is what I can get now. I would like the same data but axis labels  at 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80.

Comment: You can't do that using the normal settings as designed.  You would need a workaround.  I would force the interval by specifying a minimum Y axis value of -10 and a major division of 10.  Then I would hide (cover) the -10 axis label.

Comment: Thanks, That answers my question, can you add it as an answer? 
as I am exporting it as an image I may just hide the axis by editing in Inkscape.

Comment: @Greeny12m: Just FYI, if you "address" a comment like I did here, the person will receive an alert.  Otherwise, nobody will be aware of your posting unless they happen to view the thread.  Anyway, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that using the normal settings as they are designed. You would need a workaround.  The least effort would probably be to specify a minimum Y axis value of -10 and a major division of 10.  That would give you what you want except for a -10 axis label.  Hide (cover) that so it isn't visible.

Answer (score 2):

Format the axis, and enter this as your custom number format:

```
[>=0]0;;;
```

The `>=` part can be zero or whatever other number you wish to set it at (in my case I wanted to exclude labels before a certain year, so my custom number format was `[>=1972]0;;;`.